How to use eval() in a function from library with functions which are defined outside of this library?
I have recently developed and uploaded to PyPI a library which has a function where eval() is used:
def adv_prod(start,end,rule):
    ending_seq = list_prod([eval(rule) for i in range(start,end+1)])
    return ending_seq

If rule argument gets a string with in-library function, it works fine (prime(i) is defined in the same library file):
from supMath import adv_prod,prime

for x in range(1,11):
    print(adv_prod(1,x,"prime(i)")) 

Output:
2
6
30
210
2310
30030
510510
9699690
223092870
6469693230

But as soon as i try to input an outer function or a function from different library module I get NameError:
from supMath import adv_prod

def fib(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n==2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)

for x in range(1,11):
    print(adv_prod(1,x,"fib(i)")) 

Output: NameError: name 'fib' is not defined

Just don't use eval

from the sympy best practices: "Don’t use strings as input to functions. Rather, create the objects symbolically using Symbols and the appropriate SymPy functions, and manipulate them." if you're trying to make some sympy-esque lib, you may benefit from reading their advices

Although you got a reference to adv_prod on import, that function is still in the modMath namespace and that's the globals used by eval. You can supply your own globals to eval and that's frequently a better idea than the default. One option is to build your own dict of things that can be used by eval - fill it with the things you'd like to have available to users. Another is to add a parameter to adv_prod that supplies this data. If you don't mind doing one of these things, maybe we can work up an answer.

Oh, and the usual cautions about the dangers of running random code from some string apply.

Your supMath module knows nothing about fib() Also, assuming fib() is meant to return the Nth Fibonacci number, the implementation is flawed.

@tdelaney but how can i know which functions will user create to use them with adv_prod. The goal is to make it possible to use with custom functions. I dont really think it's possible with eval() approach at this point, maybe gonna try other options like sympy

@landee What kinds of expressions you gonna pass to eval? Just function calls with a single argument? In that case you don't need eval at all. Just pass the function and apply/call it inside adv_prod.

@phd It should be a function with a non-static variable "i" which is picked from range(start,end). It works fine with int as an argument, i can simply pass it to "rule" without using eval(), but when i try to pass not int but "i" as an argument for the "rule" function, it says "i" is not defined if i dont use eval()

This how you should do it without eval at all. Pass the function and apply/call it inside adv_prod:
def adv_prod(start, end, rule):
    ending_seq = list_prod([rule(i) for i in range(start, end+1)])
    return ending_seq

from supMath import adv_prod, prime

for x in range(1, 11):
    print(adv_prod(1, x, prime)) 

from supMath import adv_prod

def fib(n):
   …

for x in range(1, 11):
    print(adv_prod(1, x, fib)) 


I was trying to recreate this but I don't have access to the list prod function, however I do believe I know what is going on. To access external variables using eval, you can add an extra parameter, globals(), to use all global variables/funcs etc, for example:
def adv_prod(start,end,rule):
   ending_seq = list_prod([eval(rule, globals()) for i in range(start,end+1)])
   return ending_seq

Let me know if this works!

Well, it doesn't seem to be working unfortunately. Did you succeed with this?

I didn't seem to get any errors. possibly try exec() instead with globals?

could be an issue on my end.

Somehow i'm still getting errors. Anyways, thanks for help

This doesn't work because even though you get a reference to the function with from supMath import adv_prod, the function itself is in the supMath module and it gets that module's globals.

Of course. apologies for my stupidity. Thanks for helping out
